# Type mismatch: cannot convert from Boolean to boolean

Tags: java, exception, tomcat, boolean

I get this exception:

> org.apache.jasper.JasperException: Unable to compile class for JSP

I am using tomcat 5.5.23.

> org.apache.jasper.JasperException: Unable to compile class for JSP:
>     An error occurred at line: 29 in the jsp file: /jsp/general/pos/DoMultiWordFrozen.jspf
>     Type mismatch: cannot convert from Boolean to boolean
>     26:
>     27: item = (ItemType)session.getAttribute("item");
>     28: id = Integer.parseInt((String)session.getAttribute("id"));
>     29: newItem = Boolean.valueOf((String)session.getAttribute("newItem"));
>     30: changeGroup = null;
>     31:
>     32: if (!newItem && item.getMultiWordFrozen() != null && id != 0) {
>     Stacktrace:
>       org.apache.jasper.compiler.DefaultErrorHandler.javacError(jasper5-compiler-5.5.23.jar.so)
>       org.apache.jasper.compiler.ErrorDispatcher.javacError(jasper5-compiler-5.5.23.jar.so)
>       org.apache.jasper.compiler.JDTCompiler.generateClass(jasper5-compiler-5.5.23.jar.so)
>       org.apache.jasper.compiler.Compiler.compile(jasper5-compiler-5.5.23.jar.so)
>       org.apache.jasper.compiler.Compiler.compile(jasper5-compiler-5.5.23.jar.so)
>       org.apache.jasper.compiler.Compiler.compile(jasper5-compiler-5.5.23.jar.so)
>       org.apache.jasper.JspCompilationContext.compile(jasper5-compiler-5.5.23.jar.so)
>       org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServletWrapper.service(jasper5-compiler-5.5.23.jar.so)
>       org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet.serviceJspFile(jasper5-compiler-5.5.23.jar.so)
>       org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet.service(jasper5-compiler-5.5.23.jar.so)
>       javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(tomcat5-servlet-2.4-api-5.5.23.jar.so)

newitem is defined as:

```
boolean newItem = false;
```

**SOLUTION:**

This was caused because I used an **old JDK version** which does not include [autobxing](http://www.leepoint.net/notes-java/data/basic_types/autoboxing.html) 
after upgrading to jdk 1.6 (or any >= 1.5 ). It is working fine now.

Comment: try `newItem = session.getAttribute("newItem");`

Comment: Seems you're using Java version less than 1.5 for compiling JSPs. In 1.5 an unboxing (converting from 'box', i.e. Boolean object, to a simple 'boolean' type) should be done automatically. If possible, I'd suggest to use newer JDK

Comment: java -version
java version "1.6.0_20"
OpenJDK Runtime Environment (IcedTea6 1.9.10) (rhel-1.23.1.9.10.el5_7-x86_64)
OpenJDK 64-Bit Server VM (build 19.0-b09, mixed mode)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`Boolean.valueOf` returns a `Boolean`, not a `boolean` - so it sounds like you probably want:

```
newItem = Boolean.valueOf((String)session.getAttribute("newItem")).booleanValue();
```

Or, perhaps more readably:

```
String newItemAttribute = (String) session.getAttribute("newItem");
newItem = Boolean.valueOf(newItemAttribute).booleanValue();
```

I'm slightly surprised that it's not unboxing automatically for you, but I guess it depends on which version of the Java compiler Jasper is using.

Comment: so how did this code work on my old server ? only on this new server i get this message - o i guess because of the different jasper

Comment: @yossi - Perhaps you old server was running a more recent version of Java that was providing auto-boxing/unboxing.

Comment: yes you are right , it was using 1.4.2 i updated the jdk to 1.6 and it is now working fine, thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Try to replace line 29 with this:

```
newItem = Boolean.valueOf((String)session.getAttribute("newItem")).booleanValue();
```

Answer (score 1):

newItem isn't defined in your example, but I suspect it is a boolean. Add .booleanValue() to the end of line 29 to convert your parsed Boolean object to a boolean primative.